# The pre tag is shown in a larger font than other code snippets

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On Unix.SE and Meta.Unix.SE only, I see `<pre>` blocks in a larger font than `<pre><code>` or backquoted blocks. Observed in both Firefox 3.5 and Chrome 13.

This is perhaps not a bug, but it is weird. On the other SE sites, `<pre>` and backquotes and four-space indentation all result in the same font size.

[image: edit screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.